# Namespace error in visual c#

Tags: c#, namespaces, amazon-mws

I'm not quite sure how to resolve the following namespace error. I've searched this site and read what I could find online.

I start with the following statement

```
using MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Model;
```

I get the following error

```
'The type or namespace name 'Model' does not exist in the namespace 'MarketplaceWebServiceOrders' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

In terms of directory / file structure:

My project is in the visual studio project folder:
`Projects/Try1`

MarketplaceWebServiceOrders folder is in: 
`Projects/src/MarketplaceWebServiceOrders`

'Model' folder is then in this folder: 
`Projects/src/MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Model`

In case you are wondering, these files are from the amazon marketplace web services (mws) order API. Downloaded the zip and extracted to the visual studio projects folder. There was not much documentation with them.

Comment: Having a folder with that path doesn't automatically mean that you have a file with that namespace declared.

Comment: Assuming you have created the necessary reference to this assembly, first, if you haven'[t already done this, try restarting Visual Studio... sometimes t he cached metadata that drives intellisense and namespace recognition gets off-kilter and just needs to be reloaded.

Comment: Do you actually define anything with that namespace?

Comment: In JAVA the packages accord to the file-structure, in C# not. Here you have to set the namespace outside your classes that belong to it: namespace MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Model { // your class definitions here ... }

Answer (score 0):

Folder architecture SHOULD be the same than namespace architecture. But it's not an implication. You have to put your Model namespace on the MarketplaceWebServiceOrders namespace for using MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Model

All files in Model folder should have the namespace :

```
       namespace MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Model
```

Not just :

```
       namespace Model
```